# $k$ divides the product of $k$ consecutive integers (case $k=2,3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I show that for any arbitrary integer $a$, $2|(a+1)$ and $3a|(a+1)(a+2)$?

$2|(a+1)$, if $a$ is even, $2k=a$  replacing $a$ , $2k=a$ for some $k$ in $Z$

\begin{align}a(a+1)&=2k(2k+1)\\
&=4k^2+2k\\
&=2(2k^2+k)\end{align}

shows clearly that $2$ is divisible $(a+1)$

but I can't prove the second part

Comment: Could you please try to express more clearly your actual problem.

Comment: $2 \mid (a+1)$ is not true if $a$ is even.

Comment: It is not true that $2\mid (a+1)$ for "any arbitrary integer $a$". You only showed that $2\mid a(a+1)$. The second part is also false - take $a=5$.

Comment: Did you want to say $3\mid a(a+1)(a+2)$? (One of those factors is a multiple of $3$.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Maybe he meant $2|a(a+1)$ and $3|a(a+1)(a+2)$.

Comment: @u8y7541 I suspect he/she does. But I was hoping he/she would edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, the first part must have been $2|a(a+1)$ because that's how he solves it.

Comment: $2 \not \mid a+1$ for any arbitrary integer as if $a$ is even then $a+1$ is odd and $2 \not \mid a+1$.  I suspect you meant $2| a(a+1)$ which is true.  But you only provd it for and even $a$.  You must also prove it for *every* $a$ even the $a$ that aren't even.  And $3a \not \mid (a+1)(a+2)$ unless $a = 1$.

Comment: "because that's how he solves it. "  But he only solves it for even a.

Comment: ... or a =2....

Comment: There is a typo, it should be $\, 2\mid a(a+1).\, $ See the linked dupe for the general case.

Comment: There are typos. it should be $2∣a(a+1)$ and $\,3\mid a(a+1)(a+2).\,$ See the linked dupe for the general case

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are actually false.

for $a|(a+1)$ take $a = 2$. Clearly $2$ does not divide $3$

for $3a|(a+1)(a+2)$, take $a = 5$. Clearly $15$ does not divide $6*7 = 42$

Comment: Actually $3a|(a+1)(a+2)=a^2 + 3a + 2\iff a|2$ and $3|a^2 + 2$.  The only possible solution are a = 1 or a=2

Comment: The statement in the OP says for arbitrary $a$

Comment: Um... yeah?  So it is definitely false for an arbitrary $a$ because it is only true for two $a$...